# NPM Module Automatically Deletes Itself after First Use

Tags: node.js, module

I have installed Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en), v20.11.1 LTS. I am using this to connect the backend to frontend of a project that I am working on. After installation of Node.js, I ran the command `npm install express` to and it downloaded the module successfully. Immediately after, I ran the command `npm install mysql` and it hit an error that said 'Module Not Found'. Full error message is given below:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mysql
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

I always had to repair the installation and then I figured out why this was happening -- once I used `npm` to install the `express` module (or any module for that matter), the `npm` folder deleted itself, which is why the `npm-cli.js` module wasn't found. But what I do not understand is why the folder is deleting itself and how can I fix it? I have tried multiple installations and haven't figured it out yet, nor did I find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your environment variables for the node. If you have recently upgraded your node version, then there is a high chance that you have this path problem.

Go to environment variables and change the node path to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. And remove this path `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`.

I think that should work.